# how to share multiple images to whatsapp app?

Tags: android, image, whatsapp, android-sharing

How to share multiple images to all share apps like (WhatsApp, email) but when I try share multiple images to WhatsApp, I got message as : `sharing failed, please try again`. I change `setType` but not working 
please check this link

> https://trinitytuts.com/share-multiple-images-to-whatsapp-or-another-app-android/

Please check below code :

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //imageUriArray = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
                Date now = new Date();
                android.text.format.DateFormat.format("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss", now);
                aa = screenWidth * i;
                horizontal.scrollTo(aa, 0);


                try {
                    // image naming and path  to include sd card  appending name you choose for file
                    String mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/" + now + i + ".jpg";

                    // create bitmap screen capture
                    View v1 = myView.getRootView();
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v1.getDrawingCache());
                    v1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);

                    File imageFile = new File(mPath);

                    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                    int quality = 100;
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, quality, outputStream);
                    outputStream.flush();
                    outputStream.close();
                    imageUriArray.add(Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(imageFile))));
                    //openScreenshot(imageFile);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    // Several error may come out with file handling or OOM
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            toolbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/plain");
            intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUriArray);
            intent.setType("image/jpeg");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayList.add("https://trinitytuts.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/trinitylogo.png");
    arrayList.add("http://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-1hHevfC4VTQ/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAGs/Bi_dipj31f4/photo.jpg?sz=104");

    for (int ii = 0; ii < arrayList.size(); ii++) {
        LayoutInflater inflaters = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        myView = inflaters.inflate(R.layout.pager_item_multi, null);
        layMain = (LinearLayout) myView.findViewById(R.id.layMain);
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        //int screenHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        screenWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidth, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ImageView imageViews = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.img_pager_item);
        Picasso.with(this).load(arrayList.get(ii)).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher).into(imageViews);
        layMain.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        layMain.setTag("" + ii);
        layout.addView(myView);
    }
}
```

I pass Images in url and when click on button all images share on WhatsApp.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Like most social apps on Android, WhatsApp listens to intents to share media and text. Simply create an intent to share text, for example, and WhatsApp will be displayed by the system picker:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Your image url here.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

However, if you prefer to share directly to WhatsApp and bypass the system picker, you can do so by using setPackage in your intent:

```
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

This would simply be set right before you call startActivity(sendIntent);

Comment: I got image url from server.convert and display into image view in horizontal row.and share all images to others using whatsapp.not share url link ...

Comment: This is not possible, as WhatsApp does not support messages with both pictures.